# How to construct addition and multiplication table for finite field?

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-fields, cryptography

For example, choose $p(X) = X^4 + X + 1$, how to construct addition and multiplication tables for $\mathbb{F}_{2}[X] \mod{X^4 + X + 1} $ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

```
p = X^4 + X + 1;
mod[x_] := PolynomialMod[x, p, Modulus -> 2]
elements = mod[Plus @@@ Subsets[X^Range[0, 4]]]
```

And the tables are:

```
plustab = Outer[mod@*Plus, elements, elements];
timestab = Outer[mod@*Times, elements, elements];
```

If you prefer to identify the elements by their index in `elements`, you can do

```
lookuptable = AssociationThread[elements, Range[Length[elements]]];
plustabidx = Lookup[lookuptable, #] & /@ plustab;
timestabidx = Lookup[lookuptable, #] & /@ timestab;
```